# How to add two elements in a single list in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list consisting of 22 dataframes, each dataframe is a sheet from a excel file. Each DF contains a particular cities financial details that I've loaded into R using read_excel function. There a couple of cities where there are two branches hence I need to merge the two cities. How to perform this action in R.

Reproducible script:

```
> bng1 <- data.frame(parameters = c('cost','emp_count','revenue'), values = c(125,50,200))
> chn <- data.frame(parameters = c('cost','emp_count','revenue'), values = c(100,45,180))
> bng2 <- data.frame(parameters = c('cost','emp_count','revenue'), values = c(25,10,100))
> 
> mylist <- list(bng1,chn,bng2) #I got my list by creating a function using lapply and read_excel to read data into R
> mylist 
[[1]]
  parameters values
1       cost    125
2  emp_count     50
3    revenue    200

[[2]]
  parameters values
1       cost    100
2  emp_count     45
3    revenue    180

[[3]]
  parameters values
1       cost     25
2  emp_count     10
3    revenue    100
```

I need to combine details of bng1 and bng2, I'll then end up with a list consisting of two DFs: chn and bng1 or(2).

Expected output:

```
mylist
[[1]]
  parameters  values
1       cost     150
2  emp_count      60     
3    revenue     300

[[2]]
  parameters   values
1       cost      100 
2  emp_count       45
3    revenue      180
```

I have used lapply to add or subtract etc particular rows/columns of a each element in a list using

```
lapply(list, function(x) x[a,] +/- x[b,])
```

But I have no idea how to merge different elements in a single list. Could someone let me know how to perform the same.

Comment: Do you know `bng1` and `bng2` are going to be 1st and 3rd element in `mylist` ? There are no names to it.

Comment: Yes, I know the names. When I read from excel files, I've named the elements with respective excel sheet names, which are city names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your list is named you can do

```
names(mylist) <- c("bng1","chn","bng2")
list(aggregate(values~parameters, do.call(rbind, mylist[c("bng1", "bng2")]), 
               sum), mylist[["chn"]])

#[[1]]
#  parameters values
#1       cost    150
#2  emp_count     60
#3    revenue    300

#[[2]]
#  parameters values
#1       cost    100
#2  emp_count     45
#3    revenue    180
```

Or by position

```
list(aggregate(values~parameters, do.call(rbind, mylist[c(1, 3)]),
               sum), mylist[[2]])
```

and similarly using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

list(bind_rows(mylist[c(1, 3)]) %>%
            group_by(parameters) %>%
            summarise(values = sum(values)), mylist[[2]])
```